# How to reload the Main fragment after settings option change in android MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I am using tabs layout to show news content in Main fragment. This data shows based on country selection.

1. In my app, i opened Navigation drawer
2. Opened Settings menu in my app
3. Changed  language option
4. Press back..it will show home screen(Tabs)

In above case, how to reload the news content based on country selection.

In Main fragment, i am observing data from view models

Comment: you can share the same viewmodel between two fragments and observe the change

Comment: My setting option is there in Setting fragment. View model observer is there in Main fragment.How to share view model?